# Full page jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, coda-slider

I'm trying to adapt the [Coda Slider at jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/) to take up the entire page (100% width / 100% height) but as soon as I change the height of the `.scroll` class to 100%, the whole thing disappears. Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var docWidth = $(document).width();
    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    $(".scroll").css({
        "height":docHeight,
        "width":docWidth
    });
});
```

the values may need to be in pixels not %.